# Phonegap email composer fails on Android and iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-developer-app

I've been experimenting with the latest phonegap. I took the Default PhoneGap Project, and ran it on iOS and Android using the Phonegap Developer App. All worked.

Then, within the onDeviceReady event, I added some geo-location stuff. All worked fine.

I then added cordova-plugin-email-composer to my config.xml file

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" source="npm" spec="0.8.3"/>
```

and, within the `onDeviceReady` event I added

```
cordova.plugins.email.open({
    to:      'max@mustermann.de',
    cc:      'erika@mustermann.de',
    bcc:     ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
    subject: 'Greetings',
    body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
});
```

(Lifted directly from https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

In the browser ( `phonegap serve` ) this works - opens my email client. However, when run on Android and iOS (using the Phonegap Developer App) it doesn't work. The app renders, but I can't interact with it.

I've googled, and lots of people are reporting problems with the cordova-plugin-email-composer - but no solutions.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phonegap developer app I think doesn't include the plugin "cordova-plugin-email-composer" if you want still using phonegap developer app, clone https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer add the plugin a use this one instead the app from the play store

Comment: Ah! I thought that the plugins were pushed out to the Phonegap developer app as part of the zip. So in the examples - when the say add the plugin to the config.xml file, this is just an instruction for the phonegap build process, and not the developer app?

Comment: I also thought the same thing, but the phonegap developer app is just a normal build with reload functionalities even you can't use chrome://inspect with the Pronegap developer app, you need to build your own apk as debug in order to have access to that too

Comment: Which kind of makes me wonder what the advantage is in using Phonegap over Cordova... Thanks for your answer - marking as correct :) Cheers!